# Set Icon in left of app in all size of phone

Tags: flutter, dart, text, icons, alignment

i want to set text right ( width * 0.08 ) and icon left ( width * 0.08) but when i run it . itsw not work .
and when i've set padding right for text and left for icon , in other size not work .
image about web and about phone .
width = 1080 .

[image]

and this is part of my code :

```
  Container(
            child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: pageWidth * 0.08,
                    right: pageWidth * 0.09,
                    bottom: pageWidth * 0.03),
                child: Text(
                  "سلام",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: pageWidth * 0.08,
                  left: pageWidth * 0.06,
                  bottom: pageWidth * 0.04),
              child: IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Container(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    homeSettings,
                    width: pageWidth * 0.062,
                    height:pageWidth * 0.062,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
          ],
        )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `Spacer` widget between the 2 containers, like this:

```
Container(
        child: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: pageWidth * 0.08,
                right: pageWidth * 0.09,
                bottom: pageWidth * 0.03),
            child: Text(
              "سلام",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),             //Add here
        Container(
            child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: pageWidth * 0.08,
              left: pageWidth * 0.06,
              bottom: pageWidth * 0.04),
          child: IconButton(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Container(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                homeSettings,
                width: pageWidth * 0.062,
                height:pageWidth * 0.062,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ],
    )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `mainAxisAlignment` property of your row to `spaceBetween`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` or

add `const Spacer()` to add white space between them.

Or Use

```
 Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(
                  "سلام",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            )
```